# Is \int_step_inline:nnnn inserting something after it finished?

Tags: tables, expl3, latex3

The following snippet

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\trop{}{
    \int_step_inline:nnnn{0}{1}{3}{
        a & b & c & d\\
    }
    \hline
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|*{4}{X[c]|}}
    \trop
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

fail with

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi {\CT@arc@ \hrule height\arrayrulewidth }\f...
l.18 \end{tabu}

! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi {\CT@arc@ \hrule height\arrayrulewidth }\f...
l.18 \end{tabu}

! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi {\CT@arc@ \hrule height\arrayrulewidth }\f...
l.18 \end{tabu}
```

Just as if something had been inserted between the last `\\` and `\hline`, but I can't figure out what it is. Could it be a bad interaction between `tabu` and Expl syntax? I tried to put `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`Off` directly in the `tabu` and it was as if they had no effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not `tabu`, the same problem arises with the standard `tabular`.

When `\int_step_inline:nnnn` has ended its job, a new row has already started, which you can see by typesetting the table without `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\trop{}{
        \int_step_inline:nnnn{0}{1}{3}{
            a & b & c & d\\
        }
%        \hline
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \trop
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In some sense your analysis is true: it's as if there was something unexpandable at the end, that causes a new row to be started.

If your aim is to provide a number of identical rows, you can use `\prg_replicate:nn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\trop{}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { 4 } { a & b & c & d \\ }
  \hline
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \trop
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the rows have variable data depending on the current step, you can resort to building a token list and deliver it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\trop{}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { 3 }
   { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 & b & c & d \\ } }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \hline
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \trop
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, there is no need to load `xparse` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: Thanks. Any pointer on what causes this new row to be started?

Comment: @Evpok The code for `\int_step_inline:nnnn` ends with an assignment to the counter needed for being able to nest these cycles. I believe this is the culprit, but it's a necessary evil.